# Update array on state after any action of my react-redux reducer

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I am learning react-redux at the moment, already grasped the basics (I believe), I am now trying to create a notification array on my state that can be populated by several actions.

But since is a notification, I only want to add a notification after each of those actions is completed (the state is changed).

I thought about using a middleware class but that would add the notification into array before the action is computed on the reduce.

Quick example:

User logins -> dispatch action -> affects state property related to login -> adds a notification on the notification array

User adds item -> dispatch action -> affects state property related to items -> adds a notification on the notification array

These are 2 different actions, I could in the if logic of each action (on reducer) update the notification array, but seems like repeated code and I would be creating notification object on a reducer, is that okay?

So in this case where should I dispatch the action of adding a notification to the notification array?

I am looking for best practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to handle such scenario's in `reducer`. Process the data one-time and update state accordingly. In your scenario, you want to update the `notifications` array once the `action` is completed. You have to do that repeatedly because it is to be done. Here is what you can do:

```
case LOGIN:
  //checks if user is valid
  return {
     ...state
     loggedIn: true,
     user,
     notifications: state.notification.push({ id: 1, message: "Logged In!" })
  }
```

And if you want to remove a `notification` you can do that:

```
case REMOVE_NOTIFICATION:
  // You can get the notification ID you want to remove from action
  let notifications = state.notification.filter(notify => notify.id !== action.id);
  return {
     ...state
     notifications
  }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, fair enough yeah. I was thinking more deep into this, and I will have problems deleting the notifications from the array, I could use for id an hash for the message but the message will be the same, how can I overcome this? on my UI I will have several popups of notifications with a close button, and I need to correctly identify which one I am deleting from the state according to the one I am clicking, makes sense?

Comment: @TiagoM Answer Updated

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how do I the define the id for the notifcations on notification creation? use a random number?

Comment: nevermind, I can store in the redux state another variable initialize to zero and increment on each notification add, thanks!